How to proceed with "page file usage is above 80%" warning?
I'll preface this with the fact that I am a software developer by trade who has been impressed into the role of server admin.
We have a server with Windows Server 2016 with these settings:
MemoryDetails       : InstalledRamGB UsableRamGB
                      -------------- -----------
                                 192      190.63

PhysicalMemoryUsage : TotalGB UsedGB FreeGB PercentUsed
                      ------- ------ ------ -----------
                       190.63  42.42 148.21       22.25

VirtualMemoryUsage  : TotalGB UsedGB FreeGB PercentUsed
                      ------- ------ ------ -----------
                       194.63  56.58 138.04       29.08

PageFile            : Location        InitialSizeGB MaxSizeGB PeakUsageGB PeakUsePercent
                      --------        ------------- --------- ----------- --------------
                      C:\pagefile.sys             4         4           4            100

We have a particular process that runs on this server that can periodically consume upwards of 5 GB of RAM. During high memory times, we'll get these alerts:

Page file usage is above 80%, consider increasing installed memory or increasing page file size.

What's the standard protocol here?

Install more RAM - not sure if this is needed. As you can see, when the alert happened we had 42 GB of unused RAM
Change the page file size. I've never done this. Is it as simple as adjusting the page file size from 4 GB to 10 GB? Are there any issues that can arise from this?
Do nothing, leave it as-is. I'm honestly not sure if these alerts indicate a performance issue or not. Is there any harm in leaving things as-is?

Thanks

I'll post this as an answer, but I'm not an expert - like you, I started as a programmer and got shoehorned into sys admin because there was nobody else. What experience I have would suggest that a 4GB swap file is uselessly small in a system with 192GB main memory; only programs that explicitly use a "backing store" will actually use that swap file. That said, in your situation I'd go ahead and bump the swap file to at least 16GB, possibly 32GB, still smaller than physical memory would suggest but more likely to prevent those errors if your process does want 4GB of backing store. That's done in Settings | System | About | Advanced System Settings | Advanced tab | Performance Settings | Advanced if you have trouble finding it.
